# How strikethrough on item after displaying all items

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item term 1
      \item term 2
      \item term 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want is in the first slide I display all items and the second slide, I `\xout` term 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item term 1
      \item \alt<2->{\xout{term 2}}{term 2}
      \item term 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```